# Ruby minitest - better assert formatting possible?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a test for a large manually entered data structure to catch bad entries.  The structure is an array of hashes and one check is to ensure that there are no duplicated values for a specific key (ID field).

Is it possible to capture the failing `assert_empty()` data (the stuff in the returned `Expected ... to be empty` string) and format it into the `assert_empty()` message string?

The code below works but I'm performing the large operation twice; I want to perform the operation once.  Can this be done in a one-liner since the return value of the function is dumped into the minitest assertion error message?  I'm hoping for a variable of some kind?

```
assert_empty large_filtering_operation(bar), "Duplicated ID #{large_filtering_operation(bar)["id"]} detected in #{bar}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most concise you'll get is inline assignment:

```
assert_empty(result = large_filtering_operation(bar),
  "Duplicated ID #{result["id"]} detected in #{bar}")
```